# How to concatenate vectors to matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create a matrix from 3 vectors:

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([10, 0])
v2 = np.array([120, 9])
v3 = np.array([100, 7])
M = np.concatenate((v1, v2, v3))
print(M)
```

Results:

```
[10   0 120   9 100   7]
```

Desired results:

```
10  120  100
0   9     7
```

How to change the code in order to get the desired results ?

Comment: `np.array((v1, v2, v3)).T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.stack` with `axis=1`:

```
np.stack((v1, v2, v3), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 10, 120, 100],
       [  0,   9,   7]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([10, 0])
v2 = np.array([120, 9])
v3 = np.array([100, 7])
M = np.stack(v1, v2, v3), axis=1)
print(M)
```